# App size got increased after react native and gradle upgrade

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I upgraded my app's React Native version from 0.63.2 to 0.68, Gradle plugin from 4.0.1 to 7.0.4 , I thought by using higher version of react native and Gradle this will reduce my app's APK size but instead APK's size got increased by 6-7 MB .
What should I do now , my main goal is to have APK of a smaller size, is there anything to do in 0.68 RN version so that APK size can get smaller or I should downgrade to 0.63.2 ?

Difference between apks in Android Studio

[image: 1]

Comment: Hermes had its first stable release in RN 65 https://github.com/facebook/hermes/releases/tag/v0.8.1 - have you tried using it? It's supposed to reduce bundle size significantly